# Performing sum on a rdd int array

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any built in transformation to have sum on Ints of following rdd

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Int))]
```

string is the key and Int array is Value, what i need is getting the sum of all Ints as `RDD[(String, Int)]` . I tried groupByKey with no success...

Also- The result set must be again a rdd.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the objective is to sum elements of value (Int, Int), then a map transformation can achieve it:

```
val arr = Array(("A", (1, 1)), ("B", (2, 2)), ("C", (3, 3))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)

val result = rdd.map{ case (a, (b, c)) => (a, b + c) }

// result.collect = Array((A,2), (B,4), (C,6))
```

Instead if the value type is an Array, Array.sum can be used.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("A", Array(1, 1)), 
                               ("B", Array(2, 2)), 
                               ("C", Array(3, 3)))

rdd.map { case (a, b) => (a, b.sum) }
```

**Edit:**

`map` transformation does not keep the original partitioner, as @Justin  suggested `mapValues` may be more appropriate here:

```
rdd.mapValues{ case (x, y) => x + y }
rdd.mapValues(_.sum)
```

Comment: I would suggest changing this to `mapValues` to keep the hash partition that will most likely be in place

Comment: is there a way of doing this in Java?

Comment: Note extra ) required

Answer (score 2):

Here are few ways in pyspark.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([ ('A', (1,1)), ('B', (2,2)), ('C', (3, 3)) ])
rdd.mapValues(lambda (v1, v2): v1+v2).collect()
```

Or

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (k, sum(v))).collect()
[('A', 2), ('B', 4), ('C', 6)]
```

Or

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (k, (v[0] + v[1]))).collect()
[('A', 2), ('B', 4), ('C', 6)]
```

Or

```
>>> def fn(x):
...   k_s = (x[0], sum(x[1]))
...   print k_s
... 
>>> rdd.foreach(fn)
('C', 6)
('A', 2)
('B', 4)
```